# setting 404 page displays the name of 404 file

Tags: html, web, custom-error-pages

I edited the .htaccess file on my site, and added the line

> `ErrorDocument 404 page-not-found.html`

So when I put in example.com/pagethatdoesntexist, the screen just displays "page-not-found.html". Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Apache reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) documentation, URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.

So in your case, this should do the job.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html
```

With no `/`, your webpage name will be treated as a message and printed in the browser.

Comment: so... does that not bring you to the root folder automatically? because that was my belief.

Comment: Not exactly. If `/` is not given, it will always be considered as a message to be printed. Please see my edit to the answer.